# How to access array of String from other class

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to access an array of String values from another class. The problem is that I am not using a struct with constant values in it, the array is implemented as an empty one and I am filling it with data from a fro loop, then I am moving to another storyboard. And I want to use it in its UITableViewController class, is there any possible way.

```
self.authService.login(username: username, password: password, deviceToken: token) { (res, status) in   
    if status == 200 {

        let result = res as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        let array = result["depots"] as? [[String:Any]]

        for elem in array! {            
            //This is the array 
            self.depots.append(elem["number"] as! String)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {         
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"BiometryLogin") as UIViewController

            self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)         
        }       
    } else {
        self.timesWrong+=1;
        self.wrongCredentials = true

        print(res)
        group.leave()
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to access the `depots` array on the `BiometryLogin` view controller?

Comment: yes, I want to access it on BiometryLogin view controlle

Comment: Do you have a custom class for the `BiometryLogin` view controller that extends `UIViewController` ?

Comment: no, it extends UIViewController,  class BiometryAuthController:  UIViewController

Comment: do you have any idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is extending `UIViewController` creating a custom class and defining a public property, eg: `depots`

```
import UIKit

class BiometryLoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var depots: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Then on the storyboard you need to associate the custom class with the view controller, like this:

[image]

On your code will have to instantiate the view controller as a being of type `BiometryLoginViewController` and after the instantiation you can set the array data.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {         
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"BiometryLogin") as BiometryLoginViewController
        /// now you can pass the array to the destination view controller
        vc.depots = self.depots
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)         
    }
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without presenting the view, just send the array and save the data in there

Comment: If you don't want to present the view don't call `self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: I mean to not load it, not show it stay on the view I am on

Comment: this moving me to this view

Comment: if you now how to do it

Comment: and that will not save the value

Comment: but this is not saving the value of the array